# Adobe Premiere export clips in bin to individual MP4 clips

Tags: video-editing, adobe-premiere

I'm still a bit of a newcomer to Adobe Premiere, so please bear with me...

I have a 20 minute piece of footage, which I have dragged short 30 second clips from into a bin.
[image]

I now want to export each of these clips as an individual MP4 file, so that my colleagues can go through them and decide what we want to use, and what we don't.

However, I can't for the life of me work out how to do this! When I select all the clips, right click and choose 'export media' and use Adobe Media Encoder, it just outputs 20-odd full 20 minute videos, rather than giving me each clip as an individual MP4 file of 10 - 30 seconds long like I want... And I can't see an option which would allow me to specify just the section of the video covered by the clip...

I'm sure there must be something simple that I'm missing, but an hour with Google still hasn't helped...

Can anybody enlighten me on how to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a perfect solution, and is very time consuming, but I eventually managed to accomplish this by exporting each clip to a new composition (right click clip in bin -> new composition from clip) and then exporting the clip as a new piece of media (file->export->media)